# UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL Server Not Working as Expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I'm attempting to update the `LAST_INSPECTION_FW` field for all records in the `VEHICLES_FW` table with the last `JOB_DATE_FW` for records with the `REASON_CODE_FW = 35`.  However, what's happening is that once the below code is executed, it's not taking into consideration the `WHERE` clause. This causes all of the records to update when it should just be updating those with the `REASON_CODE_FW = 35`.

Is there a way to restructure this code to get it working correctly? Please help, thanks!

```
UPDATE VEHICLES_FW
 SET VEHICLES_FW.LAST_INSPECTION_FW = JOB_HEADERS_FW.FIELD2MAX
FROM VEHICLES_FW
INNER JOIN (SELECT VEHICLE_ID_FW, MAX(JOB_DATE_FW) AS FIELD2MAX
FROM JOB_HEADERS_FW
GROUP BY VEHICLE_ID_FW) AS JOB_HEADERS_FW
ON VEHICLES_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW = JOB_HEADERS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW
INNER JOIN JOB_DETAILS_FW
ON JOB_NUMBER_FW = JOB_NUMBER_FW
WHERE REASON_CODE_FW = '35'
```

Comment: HI Wayne, I suggest you start using table aliases in your queries so that when you reference a column it is clear from which table the column is from. Also, `INNER JOIN JOB_DETAILS_FW
ON JOB_NUMBER_FW = JOB_NUMBER_FW` is probably not what you intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this does what you want:

```
update v
set last_inspection_fw = (
    select max(j.job_date_fw)
    from job_headers_fw j
    inner join job_details_fw jd on jd.job_number_fw = j.job_number_fw
    where j.vehicle_id_fw = v.vehicle_id_fw and jd.reason_code_fw = 35
)
from vehicles_fw v
```

Answer (score 1):

Common Table Expressions are your friend here.  SQL Server's strange UPDATE ... FROM syntax is not.  EG

```
with JOB_HEADERS_FW_BY_VEHICLE_ID as
(
  SELECT VEHICLE_ID_FW, MAX(JOB_DATE_FW) AS FIELD2MAX
  FROM JOB_HEADERS_FW
  GROUP BY VEHICLE_ID_FW
), q as
(
Select VEHICLES_FW.LAST_INSPECTION_FW, JOB_HEADERS_FW_BY_VEHICLE_ID.FIELD2MAX NEW_LAST_INSPECTION_FW
FROM VEHICLES_FW
INNER JOIN   JOB_HEADERS_FW_BY_VEHICLE_ID 
  ON VEHICLES_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW = JOB_HEADERS_FW_BY_VEHICLE_ID.VEHICLE_ID_FW
INNER JOIN JOB_DETAILS_FW
  ON JOB_NUMBER_FW = JOB_NUMBER_FW
  WHERE REASON_CODE_FW = '35'
)
UPDATE q set LAST_INSPECTION_FW = NEW_LAST_INSPECTION_FW
```